# Detect when request is for preview generation

Tags: php

We have certain action links which are one time use only. Some of them do not require any action from a user other than viewing it. And here comes the problem, when you share it in say Viber, Slack or anything else that generates a preview of the link (or unfurls the link as Slack calls it) it gets counted as used since it was requested. 
Is there a reliable way to detect these preview generating requests solely via PHP? And if it's possible, how does one do that?

Comment: Since it's not actually a browser that is making these requests, perhaps you can inspect the user agent of the request? I know that facebook defines their user agent so that you can detect that it's them when they are scraping a URL.

Comment: For example, with slack - you could match their exact user agent - https://api.slack.com/robots

Comment: There's no way, since there are tons of clients that won't post referrers or will mask `user-agent`. If links can only be used once, you can ask users to enter something after clicking, e.g. `email` OR a simple captcha (like one from Google ala checkbox).

Comment: @Axalix anything that requires user interaction is pretty much out of question.

Comment: @lix that was obvious solution I figured but it doesn't seem reliable at all, unless we just do most common things.

Comment: @IgorYavych - indeed, as axalix mentioned, this data is easily manipulated by the client.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with 100% accuracy in PHP alone, as it deals with HTTP requests, which are quite abstracted from the client. Strictly speaking you cannot even guarantee that user **have actually seen** the response, even tho it was legitimately requested by the user.

The options you have:

- use checkboxes like "I've read this" (violates no-action requirement)
- use javascript to send "I've read this" request without user interaction (violates PHP alone requirement)
- rely on cookies: redirect user with set-cookie header, then redirect back to show content and mark the url as consumed (still not 100% guaranteed, and may result with infinite redirects for bots who follow 302 redirects, and do not persist cookies)
- rely on request headers (could work if you had a finite list of supported bots, and all of them provide a signature)

Answer (score 0):

I've looked on the entire internet to solve this problem. And I've found some workarounds to verify if the request is for link preview generation.

Then, I've created a tool to solve it. It's on GitHub:
https://github.com/brunoinds/link-preview-detector

You only need to call a single method from the class:

```
use Brunoinds\LinkPreviewDetector\LinkPreviewDetector;

$response = LinkPreviewDetector::isForLinkPreview();
//returns a boolean (true/false). If it is true, it means the request is coming from a link preview crawler.
```

I hope to solve your question!

You can install it from Composer using:

```
composer require brunoinds/link-preview-detector
```

Comment: Great idea, but from where do you gather data to BlockList.json? Or have you done it manually? I ran in to this bot (Google-PageRenderer) via a android SMS preview. I guess the BlockList needs to be updated. It would be great if there is a website that gather and update bots, specifically preview bots. Do you know any?

Comment: I've made a update on the package, it is now Composer available. The block-list it is based on the "monperrus/crawler-user-agents" file, that is updated every week.